# handing over a param from a rails form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a form tag to implement a search text_field.

```
<% form_tag catalogues_path(:select => params[:select]), :method => "get" do %>
```

The problem is the catalogues_path which should consist the select
param. Unfortunately the select param doesn't get handed over in the
upper example...

The result is the same as if I would just write:

```
<% form_tag catalogues_path, :method => "get" do %>
```

Any hint will be appreciated!

Thanks
Makrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi If you want to sent something from your form as `params[:select]` use `hidden_field_tag :select, :value=>params[:select]` inside your form or do you want to have something like

`http://localhost/catalogues?select=something` in your url ?

Comment: hidden_field_tag :select, params[:select] did it! the :value gets added to the select field. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

it work's for me .

why don't you write html directly then

```
<form method="get" action="/catalogues?select=<%= params[:select] %>">

</form>
```

Comment: cause then the localisation param will not get added to the link like it should... But this could also be a solution!